# Rails Grape show 404 page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger, swagger-ui, ruby-grape

I am a beginner in `Grape`, I want to show my api list by using `swagger-ui`.
I put swagger html in `public/swagger`, and I access [localhost:3000/swagger](http://localhost:3000/swagger)

However, it keep showing `404 not found`. I thought it's causing by Grape configuration.

Here is **api.rb**

```
#app/api/twitter/api/api.rb

require 'grape'
module Twitter
  class API < Grape::API
    version 'v1', using: :header, vendor: 'twitter'
    format :json
    prefix :api
    add_swagger_documentation

    resource :statuses do
      desc 'Return a public timeline.'
      get :public_timeline do
        Status.limit(20)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do it manually by putting swagger html somewhere.

You could use gem [grape-swagger](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-swagger) provided by Grape team, add two lines in you `config.ru`.

```
require 'grape-swagger'

module API
  class Root < Grape::API
    format :json
    ...
    add_swagger_documentation
  end
end
```

then you could access swagger doc at http://localhost:3000/swagger_doc

Comment: It looks reasonable. But um...I am not sure what is going on, but I still get the `404 not found` page.Seems like I can only access the path which I've define on `api.rb`.

Comment: You added the gem to Gemfile, run `bundle install`, and restarted the server, right?

Comment: Yeah, sure, I add this gem swagger already. Here is Github link: https://github.com/fifiteen82726/grape_practice/

Comment: @CodaChang Your grape is a Rails engine, so the url should be http://localhost:3000/api/swagger_doc